# Как сделать ромб border-ми css

Tags: html, css, css3, веб-программирование

Как сделать ромбик свойством `border`, по середине ромбика линию и чтобы при наведении на ромбик и на линию, ширина линии уменьшалась до **0**.

Как это сделать, помогите?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/L4owdt7c/)

```css
.moo {
  height: 3px; width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 150px;
}
.moo:after{ content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid orange;
  top: -150px; left: 0;
}
.moo:before{ content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid orange;
  top: 3px; left: 0;
}
.line { 
  height: 3px; width: 100px; 
  background-color: #045acf;
  margin: auto; transition: 1s linear;
}
.moo:hover .line { width: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="moo">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Не знаю, насколько понятно это будет для вас... будут вопросы - задавайте в комментарии)

P.s. У самих блоков `:after` и `:before` нулевой размер. Добавляются невидимые рамки во всех направлениях, по 50 пикселей (выделено красными линиями на картинке), но потом в коде добавляется еще один `border-bottom: 100px solid orange` - он записан позже, поэтому получает приоритет и отображается как надо. А вот top: -150px уже складывается от высот бордеров 50 (невидимого) + 100px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.P.s. невидимые бордеры во всех направлениях нужны, чтобы все они получились именно треугольниыми, вокруг элемента нулевого размера. Иначе если добавить просто один бордер снизу - он во-первых будет прямоугольным, во-вторых будет зависимым от размеров блока... а блок нулевой - значит и бордер будет с высотой 100px, но шириной 0... и не будет виден.

Comment: Почему вопрос минусют ?

Comment: @Leks Не знаю... наверно потому что нет конкретики.